# How to scrape txn fee data from etherscan.io?

Tags: erc-20

I have a long list of TxID's, how can I scrape "txn fee" from every transaction (how much they have paid on chain) without looking at any transaction manually?

For an ERC20 token transfers.

Answer (score 1):

You can get this information from [any Ethereum node](https://ethereumnodes.com/) for example using [Python](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

No Etherscan needed for anything.